# Error in metadata: Cannot validate serde: com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde in Hive

Tags: csv, hive, loading

> FAILED: Error in metadata: Cannot validate serde: com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde
>       FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Error happens like above. I don't know why I think I have jar file in location of `/usr/lib/hive/lib` with name as of `hive-serde-0.10.0-cdh4.2.1.jar`

```
create table timesheet 
(BibNum bigint, 
Title string, 
Author string, 
ISBN string, 
PublicationYear 
string, 
Publisher string, 
Subjects string, 
ItemType string, 
ItemCollection String, 
FloatingItem string, ItemLocation string, 
ReportDate string, ItemCount int
) row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde2.csv.CSVSerde' 
with serdeproperties ( "seperator 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' 
with serdeproperties ( "seperatorChar" = "\t", "quo.csv.CSVSerde' 
with serdeproperties ( "seperatorChar" = "\t", "quoteChar" ="'", "escapeChar" = "\\" )
```

Stored as textfile; this is my command I used for:

[image]

Comment: what command did you use to run it? and what does your `hive-site.xml` look like?

Comment: I do not know what hive-site.xml is .. What is that? Sorry

Comment: it's the configuration file for hive

Comment: are you using a cloudera VM?

Comment: Yes , that's right

Comment: I put up all my jar files as a screenshot.

Comment: that's an old version of hive, it doesn't look like it comes with the proper serde and I can't find a jar of one compiled for that version

Comment: try adding this jar https://github.com/downloads/ogrodnek/csv-serde/csv-serde-1.1.2.jar

Comment: Okay, I will try it thanks

Comment: Omg, I cannot access that link in vm.

Comment: Do you think I need to download newest Hive ?

Comment: not necessarily, if you're just using the vm for learning I would ditch it in favor of a newer one or a cloud service

Comment: I see, I got jar file you sent with link, but still not working.. I will get a new Hive version. By the way, can I just download only Hive in this VM ?

Comment: probably, I don't use cloudera much.

Comment: hy, BTW, if we use the above jar, will the issue resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn how to use `Hive` try downloading a newer VM like [HDP 2.6](https://hortonworks.com/downloads/#data-platform) or spinning up a [dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) / [emr](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) instance in the cloud. Datalab has [a good number of tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials)

Honestly, I'd try to learn spark. Then you can use [Databricks Community Edition](http://community.cloud.databricks.com/) to learn in your browser

Comment: Thank you so much, by the way , in google cloud platform, it also supports Hive environment ?

Comment: yup, google (GCP) has dataproc which is essentially Hive and Spark

Comment: Oh, that sounds so interesting, do we need to set up something? I mean we don't need to download any , right?

Comment: no downloads, dataproc can be deployed in the cloud. google has a very generous free-trial period of a year and something like $300

Comment: Oh, actually I have been an user of google cloud due to the fact that we deal with it in my class.

Answer (score 0):

Download this
https://github.com/downloads/ogrodnek/csv-serde/csv-serde-1.1.2.jar

Run below line in Hive Query

```
add jar hdfs:///user/cloudera/csv-serde-1.1.2.jar;
```